# Pass an array from PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php

hi i have a big problem i try 3 weaks to solve it but i didn't make anything i have or an errors or i don't take nothing from the results.
i pas an array from query ST_AsGeoJSON from a php code in the javascript code.
there are in the same file html this two codes i get the array from php to javascrypt with this line of code

```
var jsonAr= <?php echo json_encode($Arresu) ?>;
```

if i print the jsonAr i receve with `document.write(jsonAr);` it is give me this format

```
{ "type":"LineString","coordinates":[[25.9980559326738,39.2420282528175],......,,[26.0486275566016,39.2291388086281]]},{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[26.0486275566016,39.2291388086281],......[]]}
```

if i try to take the coordinates and pot it in an array i try this  `jsonAr.coordinates[0][0]` but i did not take any result , i don't know how i take the coordinates

Comment: add `console.log('jsonAr');` after the variable definition to see what JS has for that variable. This will help you diagnose your own problem more easily.

Comment: you need to parse that JSON string first. Use `var jsonAr = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($Arresu) ?>);`

Comment: if i use JSON.parser is say me JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 647 of the JSON data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonAr.coordinates[0]` will give you the first coordinate.  `jsonAr.coordinates[0][0]` only gives you the first number of the first coordinate.

Comment: I try it but the firefox console say jsonAr.coordinates is undefined

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to assign two values to your variable

```
jsonAr = {...},{...}
```

Maby you want to try somethig like this:

```
jsonAr = [{...},{...}]
jsonAr[0].coordinates[0][0] //25.9980559326738
```

Or

```
jsonAr = [{...},{...}]
draw_function(jsonAr[0].coordinates[0][0],jsonAr[1].coordinates[0][0]) //25.9980559326738,26.0486275566016
```